# Missing some folders after packing ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I did some compilation changes in `ext/extconf.rb` file of `eventmachine-1.0.0` ruby gem, then I ran `gem build`.

After I unpacked the same gem, but `ext` folder is alone and remaining folders are missing. Any idea?

Here you can find the log:

```
eventmachine-1.0.0]$ ls
docs  eventmachine.gemspec  examples  ext  Gemfile  GNU  java  lib  LICENSE  Rakefile  rakelib  README.md  tests  tmp
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$ gem build eventmachine.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: eventmachine
  Version: 1.0.0
  File: eventmachine-1.0.0.gem
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$ mkdir Temp
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$ mv eventmachine-1.0.0.gem Temp
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$ cd Temp/
Temp]$
Temp]$ gem unpack eventmachine-1.0.0.gem
Unpacked gem: '/home/irgpan/temp/ruby_gems/Gem_compile/eventmachine-1.0.0/Temp/eventmachine-1.0.0'
Temp]$
Temp]$ cd eventmachine-1.0.0/
eventmachine-1.0.0]$
eventmachine-1.0.0]$ ls
ext  README.md
eventmachine-1.0.0]$


**find the spec file below**

# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
require File.expand_path('../lib/em/version', __FILE__)

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = 'eventmachine'
  s.version = EventMachine::VERSION
  s.homepage = 'http://rubyeventmachine.com'
  s.rubyforge_project = 'eventmachine'

  s.authors = ["Francis Cianfrocca", "Aman Gupta"]
  s.email   = ["garbagecat10@gmail.com", "aman@tmm1.net"]

  s.files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.extensions = ["ext/extconf.rb", "ext/fastfilereader/extconf.rb"]
  s.add_development_dependency 'rake-compiler', '~> 0.8.1'
  s.add_development_dependency 'yard', ">= 0.7.2"
  s.add_development_dependency 'bluecloth'

  s.summary = 'Ruby/EventMachine library'
  s.description = "EventMachine implements a fast, single-threaded engine for arbitrary network
communications. It's extremely easy to use in Ruby. EventMachine wraps all
interactions with IP sockets, allowing programs to concentrate on the
implementation of network protocols. It can be used to create both network
servers and clients. To create a server or client, a Ruby program only needs
to specify the IP address and port, and provide a Module that implements the
communications protocol. Implementations of several standard network protocols
are provided with the package, primarily to serve as examples. The real goal
of EventMachine is to enable programs to easily interface with other programs
using TCP/IP, especially if custom protocols are required."

  s.rdoc_options = ["--title", "EventMachine", "--main", "README.md", "-x", "lib/em/version", "-x", "lib/jeventmachine"]
  s.extra_rdoc_files = ["README.md"] + `git ls-files -- docs/*`.split("\n")
end
```

Comment: Please, provide `.gemspec` file.

Comment: .gemspec file added along with comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this in console at gem root directory: `git add -A` and then build gem again.

As you can see here `s.files =`git ls-files`.split("\n")` files appends via git ls-file cmd, so you should to maintain files that you need to include via local git repository.